# PHP Update Statement with WHILE loop and array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My update statement is not working. It shows "RECORD UPDATED" but not updating the table. Here is the code, please help.

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Connection error");
mysqli_select_db($db,"suhaib")or die("dbase error");
```

Creating associative array and running WHILE loop

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
$sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM forma");
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>
<form name="update1" action="" method="GET">
DataNumber:<input type="text" name="datanum" 
value="<?php echo $result['datanumber']; ?>">
Date:<input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $result['date']; ?>">
Type:<input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $result['type']; ?>">
Subject:<input type="text" name="subject" 
value="<?php echo $result['subject']; ?>">
Amount:<input type="text" name="amount" 
value="<?php echo $result['amount']; ?>">
SOE:<input type="text" name="soe" value="<?php echo $result['soe']; ?>">
Note:<input type="text" name="note" value="<?php echo $result['note']; ?>">
Liquidate:<input type="text" name="liquidate" 
value="<?php echo $result['liuidatedate']; ?>">
Checker Info:<input type="text" name="checkerinfo" 
value="<?php echo $result['checkerinfo']; ?>">
Accounting Info:<input type="text" name="accountingconfir" 
value="<?php echo $result['accountingconfir']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="update" name="upd">
</form>
<?php }} ?>
```

Update statement to update the table. Table is not being updated but it shows the message "RECORD UPDATED"

```
if(isset($_GET['upd'])){
$datanum=$_GET['datanum'];
$date=$_GET['date'];
$type=$_GET['type'];
$subject=$_GET['subject'];
$amount=$_GET['amount'];
$soe=$_GET['soe'];
$note=$_GET['note'];
$liquidate=$_GET['liquidate'];
$checkerinfo=$_GET['checkerinfo'];
$accounting=$_GET['accountingconfir'];

$up="UPDATE forma SET datanumber='$datanum' , date='$date' , 
type='$type' , subject='$subject' ,
amount='$amount', soe='$soe' , note='$note', liuidatedate='$liquidate' ,
checkerinfo='$checkerinfo', accountingconfir='$accounting'";
mysqli_query($db, $up);
echo "record updated";
```

Comment: you update whole table data or particulare id wise

Comment: I added the `<?php` tags to you question that way it colors the HTML correctly.

Comment: Check for errors from the query: `mysqli_query($db, $up) or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: You should also learn how to use prepared statements. Your code is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: And tabs ^, just saying I can't read that...  Ps `but it shows the message "RECORD UPDATED"` you not checking if it failed in any way, it just outputs that line as it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, your missing something very important here

```
 $up="UPDATE
        forma
    SET
        datanumber='$datanum',
        date='$date',
        type='$type',
        subject='$subject',
        amount='$amount',
        soe='$soe',
        note='$note',
        liuidatedate='$liquidate' ,
        checkerinfo='$checkerinfo',
        accountingconfir='$accounting'";
```

I mean unless you are trying to overwrite all the data in your database.  Do you see it...

```
   Where ... ?
```

Omitting the WHERE clause will update every row with this data.  Hopefully

- you intended this ( unlikly )
- you have a backup
- your still just using test data on a test site
- your query is broken.

You also either missed part of your code in the question or, you have a syntax error

```
 if(isset($_GET['upd'])){
    ....
```

No closing `}` in your question.

As to your issue, I suggest turning on error reporting and display errors like this

```
<?php  //right at top of php after the tag
    error_reporting(-1);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This way PHP will tell you what is wrong.